# DNF. How to find which group package belongs to?

Tags: dnf

I'm using fedora 22 and dnf-1.1.2-4.fc22.noarch

As an use-case scenario: I found that strace package is not installed. I want to figure out if this package belongs to any other group, to install software that I'll probably will need too for similar tasks.

I found this brute-force way(grepping for 3 spaces bacause group names start with this indent):

```
dnf grouplist | grep '   ' | while read line; do dnf groupinfo "$line"; done
```

Then redirect this output to a file, search for a package name, and find a group name there.

Comment: I downloaded the comps xml files and used several iterations of csplit to do something similar recently. Using an xslt tool would be better probably. I'm also interested to learn about a better way to do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since Fedora 26, the following works:

```
dnf repoquery --groupmember <pkg-name>
```

See the [bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1462486) where this feature was implemented.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an example of something that seems to work in my fedora 21, but dnf is still changing, so try it and see:

```
$ pkg=fvwm
$ dnf groupinfo '*' | sed -n '/Group:/h;/'"$pkg"'/{x;p;x;p}'
Group: Window Managers
   fvwm
```

The `sed` holds (h) each group heading, and then when the package matches
exchanges hold and pattern (x), prints the heading (p), exchanges back and
prints the package.

Comment: Thank you. It is definetely better than mine. But why dnf doesn't have native command for this?

Comment: dnf is a redhat product, and work in progress. you could try submitting a request for enhancement to the redhat bugzilla list, but there are already over 1000 entries mostly marked NEW, so good luck with that.

Comment: 1 char shorter :) `dnf groupinfo \* | sed -n '/Group:/h;/'"$pkg"'/{H;x;p}'` just append the pattern space to the hold space, exchange and print.

Comment: I'm not using an english locale, and the output was erroneous, so better force the command with C locale as in: `LC_ALL=C dnf groupinfo '*' | sed -n '/Group:/h;/'"$pkg"'/{x;p;x;p}'`

Answer (score 1):

### Another way using `awk`:

Package `strace`

```
pkg="strace"; dnf groupinfo '*' | awk -F": " '/^Group/ {group=$2} /'"$pkg"'/ {print group}'
```

Output shows:

```
Security Lab
C Development Tools and Libraries
```

---

Package `fvwm`

```
pkg="fvwm"; dnf groupinfo '*' | awk -F": " '/^Group/ {group=$2} /'"$pkg"'/ {print group}'
```

Output shows:

```
Window Managers
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, we can list all groups and their packages by

```bash
# save the result to /tmp/all-group-packages
dnf group list | sed -n 's/   //p' | sed -E "s/(.*)/'\0'/" | xargs dnf group info >/tmp/all-group-packages
```